# Nestjs dynamic module, configured with forRoot in the root module(AppModule). How to inject it into the child modules?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a dynamic module configured in the imports section of AppModule by passing params into the forRoot method. Later I want to use service from that module in a few of my child modules. But how to provide this configured instance to those modules?

- I can use the @Global decorator on that dynamic module and then the service inside it will be accessible to all the modules. But I want to provide it to a few only modules instead.

```
    @Module({})
    @Global()
    export class JwtModule {
      static forRoot(options: JwtModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
        return {
          module: JwtModule,
          providers: [
            {
              provide: CONFIG_OPTIONS,
              useValue: options,
            },
            JwtService,
          ],
          exports: [JwtService],
        };
      }
    }
```

```
    @Module({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true,
          envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.ENV}`,
          ignoreEnvFile: process.env.ENV === 'prod',
          validationSchema: Joi.object({
            ENV: Joi.string().valid('dev', 'prod', 'test'),
            DB_NAME: Joi.string().required(),
            TOKEN_SECRET: Joi.string().required(),
          }),
        }),
        GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
          driver: ApolloDriver,
          autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          type: 'sqlite',
          database: process.env.DB_NAME,
          synchronize: process.env.ENV !== 'prod',
          logging: true,
          entities: [User],
        }),
        UsersModule,
        CommonModule,
        JwtModule.forRoot({
          tokenSecret: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
        }),
      ],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

```
    @Module({
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
        // JwtModule.forRoot({ tokenSecret: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET }),
      ],
      providers: [UserService, UserResolver],
    })
    export class UsersModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do then, rather than import it in the `AppModule`, is make a wrapper module that imports this dynamic module with its configuration, and then exports the module as well. Then, where you need this configured dynamic module, you can import the wrapper and have access to the dynamic module's services.

Example:

```js
@Moudle({
  imports: [JwtModule.forRoot(jwtModuleOptions)],
  exports: [JwtModule],
})
export class ConfiguredJwtModule {}


@Module({
  imports: [ConfiguredJwtModule],
  providers: [FooService],
})
export class FooModule {}

@Injectable()
export class FooService {
  constructor(private readonly jwt: JwtService) {}

  ...
}
```

The above (assuming that `JwtModule.forRoot()` has `JwtService` in the`exports` array), works with the configuration provided to `JwtModule.forRoot()` without having to provide it again.

Comment: Jay, it's a great approach, thank you. But I still would like to centralize providing all parameters and configs inside the root module. Maybe some more nestjs-ish way exists for that? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it's called making the module `@Global()`, which you already said you didn't want to do

Comment: But spreading access all over the app feels to me maybe a bit overkill. Looks like lack of a standard way for configuring in one centralized place and consuming by demand where it's needed. Thank you

Comment: Nest's provider access is not "top down" (parent to child modules), but rather "bottom up", so if you want to make a centralized module that does this, you can, but the `AppModule` is not the place to do it

Comment: Actually, I don't need it to follow a top-bottom approach. A better way looks like having DynamicModule.register() in one whatever place and DynamicModule.forOption() in every place I want to consume it. Maybe I could save the config info in a static prop on the register call and then use it on forOption in every specific module that needs it. But here we will come to a race condition for this saved static config.

Comment: And maybe ideally I would expect it to be configured in the root module with imports[DM.forFoot..] and just consumed in a specific one with just imports[DM], but unfortunately, it will not work with the dynamic module.